# Does "chaining" work in Pokemon X and Y?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Now that the Poke Radar is back in X and Y, does anyone know if you can "chain" to have an increased chance of shiny Pokemon like in Diamond, Pearl, and Platinum? If you don't know what "chaining" is: http://bmgf.bulbagarden.net/f226/shiny-pok%C3%A9mon-pok%C3%A9radar-19695/

Comment: Yes, the same thing now works with the consecutive fishing technique as well. http://www.serebii.net/xy/fishchain.shtml http://www.serebii.net/xy/pokeradar.shtml

Comment: @C-dizzle That sounds like an answer. Would you like to post it as such? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain for shiny Pokemon using the PokeRadar. You have to be careful you don't break the chain. Using repels helps because you won't encounter Pokemon while walking in the grass, instead you will only encounter the ones found with the PokeRadar. X/Y now has grass that will shake, but there might not be Pokemon found in that patch. Stay away from the outer edges of a grass patch, most of the time the Pokemon you encounter will be a different one that you started chaining with. Encountering a different Pokemon will also break the chain. [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/pokeradar.shtml) is showing that a shiny encounter could come around 40 successful chains.

Another feature added to the X/Y games is [Consecutive Fishing.](http://www.serebii.net/xy/fishchain.shtml) Unlike the PokeRadar, you do not need to keep encountering the same Pokemon over and over again. But you MUST be successful in reeling in Pokemon without them getting away. I have been very lucky in the consecutive fishing technique, encountering a shiny around 30-40 successful reels. This can be done with any of the fishing rods. One important note when doing this, DO NOT move from the spot you are fishing in. Once you find a spot, keep fishing there. If you want to increase your chances to get a consecutive fish, get a Pokemon with the [Suction Cups](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/suctioncups.shtml) ability.

Things that will not break the chain:

- Catching Pokemon,
- Making them faint,
- Running away from battle.
- Using the menu (to move Pokemon around, use items, etc)

I have not tested going into the PSS because there is a possibility it could break the chain if you use GTS, Wonder Trade, etc...

Comment: Also, in the chain fishing, if you get extremely unlucky and not find a Pokemon, even with Suction Cups, the chain will break.  Also, reeling too fast or slow breaks the chain.

Answer (score -2):

Already have 34 shiny pokemo within 30 hours of fishing when the chain is above 40 and your rod is direct besides a rock and having a suction cups ability 1st in the party makes the chance of encountering a shiny pokemon 1 on 200 you can have more than 1 shiny in a chain